# What are the correct interpretations for these basic probability questions?

Tags: probability

I have this homework on basic probability for my engineering mathematics course, but I don't understand these two sub-questions.

Here is the text.

> The probabilities of the monthly snowfall exceeding 10 cm at a
>   particular location in the months of December, January and February
>   are 0.20, 0.40 and 0.60, respectively.

Here are the questions that I do not know how to interpret.

> (For a particular winter:)
>
> 1. What is the probability of receiving at least 10 cm snowfall in a
>      month, in at least two of the three months of that winter?
> 2. Find the expected number of months in which monthly snowfall does not exceed 10 cm.

Given and my assumptions:

1. There are three consecutive months, each with a corresponding probability of exceeding 10 cm snowfall.
2. A month of exceeding snowfall does not affect the amount of snowfall for the next month (not to be confused with the months' relationship in a tree diagram, they are still related)

Sorry to ask about this. English is not my main language.

Comment: For what it's worth, your mastery of English surpasses that of many native English speakers!

Answer (score 0):

More assumptions are needed.  If $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are the amounts of snowfall in each month, (2) says $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent.
But that does not imply $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent, which is what you need.
In that case, if $p_i = P(X_i \ge 10)$, the answer to (1) would be
$P(X_1 \ge 10, X_2 \ge 10) + P(X_1 \ge 10, X_3 \ge 10) + P(X_2 \ge 10, X_3 \ge 10) - 2 P(X_1 \ge 10, X_2 \ge 10, X_3 \ge 10) = p_1 p_2 + p_1 p_3 + p_2 p_3 - 2 p_1 p_2 p_3$.

Comment: I can solve the problems. What I really is need is how to interpret those questions. The grammar, the way the question is stated, eludes me. I'm looking for the interpretation and not necessarily the solution. No offence.

Answer (score 0):

a)  The probability of the monthly snowfall NOT exceeding $10 $ cm is $0.8, 0.6$, and $0.4$. Since these are assumed to be independent (not really a safe assumption), the probability of all three being less than $10$ cm is:
\begin{align*}
0.8 \times 0.6 \times 0.4 = 0.19200  
\end{align*}

b)
All $3 = .2 \times .4 \times .6 = 0.04800$

Dec & Jan & not Feb  $ =0.2 \times 0.4 \times 0.4 = 0.03200$

Dec, not Jan, Feb $= 0.2 \times 0.6 \times 0.6 = 0.07200$

not Dec, Jan, Feb $= 0.8 \times 0.4 \times 0.6 = 0.19200 $

Now add up these four numbers: $0.34400 $

c)
Consecutive
Dec-Jan-not Feb $= 0.03200$

Jan-Feb-not Dec $= 0.19200$

$0.19200 + 0.03200 = 0.22400$
Not Consecutive

Dec - Feb-not Jan $= 0.07200$

$0.07200 + 0.19200 + 0.03200 = 0.29600$

probability of consecutive $= 0.244/0.296 = 0.756$